# How to select currency from drop down and it changes all currency cells across workbook quickly

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a private excel program that has multiple different currency format cells across the workbook.

I want to change all currency cells in the workbook from one currency to a selected currency.

This process must happen quickly and efficiently.

Any ideas?

I have been looking at multiple threads and no luck. I do not seam to find any threads that can quickly change the currency symbol of every currency cell.

Here are links to some sites I have tried:
- https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/vba-code-to-change-currency-format.3861711/
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5828423e-96dd-4cae-8404-7d5d8adb328c/finding-all-currency-formatted-cells-and-change-the-currency-symbol?forum=exceldev
- https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/4dcha1/i_need_a_way_to_change_all_currency_cells_across/
- https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/67104-change-currency-symbol-from-list?t=77206
-https://chandoo.org/forum/threads/how-to-change-the-currency-symbol-dynamically-in-excel.7673/
-https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2010/06/23/conditional-formatting-for-currency-symbol/

I have not included all threads I looked at previously.
I just require something quick and efficient.

CODE:

```
Dim cur As Range
Set cur = Range("e12")


If Not Application.Intersect(cur, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then
 If cur = "Dollar" Then

    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    End If



ElseIf cur = "Euro" Then

    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    End If



ElseIf cur = "Pound" Then
    'dollar to dirham
    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    End If



ElseIf cur = "Dirham" Then
    'dollar to dirham
    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    End If




ElseIf cur = "Rand" Then

    If Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ " Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00_ ;_-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;_-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;_-@_ "
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
            "_-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;-* #,##0.00 [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-* ""-""?? [$?.?.?-ar-AE]_-;_-@_-"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    ElseIf Sheets("Summary").Range("e15").NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)" Then
    Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = _
    "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Application.ReplaceFormat.NumberFormat = _
        "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    Cells.Replace What:="", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:= _
            xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True, ReplaceFormat:=True
    End If
'
'
'
'
End If
End If
```

Comment: How big is the workbook?

Comment: @Underverse 35 sheets

Comment: You can write a macro that downloads a current conversion table, and then uses that to process the change and reformat.  Also take a look at the late Chip Pearson's article on [VBA arrays and worksheet ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) as processing within a VBA array will be probably an order of magnitude faster than working to/form the worksheet directly. Edit your question to show your code and your problems if you run into problems with this approach.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why not just define those ranges as a variable and manipulate the formatting in code? If you also need to convert the value you can just change the cell.Value as well. Are  you familiar with assigning ranges to variables and manipulating their properties?

Comment: @Underverse Added relevant code, no luck

Comment: @nbayly added code, no luck

Comment: @RonRosenfeld added code still no luck

Comment: What does "no luck" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Solution if simple:

Make if statements the option in drop down.

Make this code run anytime a new selection is chosen and run all replace functions as none will evaluate a error. Easy bypass but effective nonetheless.

Code:

Range("o14").NumberFormat = "*-[$$-en-US]* #,##0.00* ;*-[$$-en-US]* -#,##0.00 ;*-[$$-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;*-@* "
            Range("o18").NumberFormat = "*($* #,##0.00*);*($* (#,##0.00);*($* ""-""??*);*(@*)"
                    Range("o16").NumberFormat = "*-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-en-GB]* #,##0.00_-;*-[$£-en-GB]* ""-""??*-;*-@*-"
                            Range("o15").NumberFormat = "*-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]*-;-* #,##0.00 [$€-de-DE]*-;*-* ""-""?? [$€-de-DE]*-;*-@*-"
                                    Range("o17").NumberFormat = "*-[$" & "AED" & "-en-US]* # ##0.00_) ;[Color46]*-([$" & "AED" & "-en-US]* -# ##0.00) ;*-[$" & "AED" & "-en-US]* ""-""??_ ;*(@*)"